# Cannot dynamically create an instance of type 'System.Text.Json.Nodes.JsonObject'. Reason: No parameterless constructor defined

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Basically, I have this class in my C# project:

```cs
public class Item
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string AppId { get; set; }

    public JsonObject Fields { get; set; }
}
```

And I've created a couple of items in a MongoDB using a POST request with this body:

```
{
  "AppId":"(an already existing app id)",
  "Fields": {
    "NombreCliente": "Pepillo",
    "Email": "pepiko@email.com",
    "Telefono": "pp56656784",
    "Localidad": "Pepeland",
    "Facturas": ["848435498","0564864984"]
  }
}
```

And they were correctly created.

The problem occurs whenever I try to get these items. The error in the title pops up:

> An error occurred while deserializing the Fields property of class divitiae_api.Models.Item: Cannot dynamically create an instance of type 'System.Text.Json.Nodes.JsonObject'. Reason: No parameterless constructor defined.

What should I do? I'm really lost here... I've tried creating a parameterless constructor but it still keeps failing...

**UPDATE**

To create an Item I'm using the next method. I can't use a direct "Item" because it throws an exception regarding circular  reference in the Field property, so I serialize it to a JSON string and then insert it like that into the collection:

```cs
public async Task InsertItem(JsonObject item)
{
    var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve
    };
    var jsonString = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(item, options);

    var document = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(jsonString);
    var collection2 = _repository.db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Items");
    await collection2.InsertOneAsync(document);
}
```

And this is the one I'm using to GET them:

```cs
public async Task<List<Item>> GetAllAppItems(string appId)
{
    var filter = Builders<Item>
        .Filter
        .Eq(s => s.AppId, appId);

    return await Collection.FindAsync(new BsonDocument()).Result.ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: Hi, are you using the same class `Item` for creating item in collection? If yes, can you share the code for the insertion? Would like to check whether is there any conflict before provide the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using JsonObject and not a defined type?

Comment: @YongShun not really using the same class. Just added the code you asked

Comment: @tymtam felt like it made sense to use it since, in the body I'm sending, the "Fields" field is a json object... what would you change it for?

Comment: A concrete class with properties.

Comment: @tymtam ok I got you, thing is I can't create a Field class with its properties because these Fields are fully customizable and created by the user, that's why I can't know what the properties are going to be... One item might have 3 fields, another one 8...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think that MongoDB .NET Driver is unable to know how to map an object to `JsonObject` as `JsonObject` is not under its library.

An easy fix is to modify the `Fields` data type to either `object` or `dynamic`.

```cs
public class Item
{
    ...

    public dynamic Fields { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I've tried modifying it like that. The creations went nice, but it threw the same error when trying to get them. I've added code to the description above, maybe it helps

Comment: I try to reproduce on my local side but it works correctly with I specify the `Fields` type as `dynamic/object`. Did you really change the type for `Fields` property? Cause if you changed you won't get the same error message for "System.Text.Json.Nodes.JsonObject"

Comment: Okey I don't know what I did wrong but tried it again and it worked! Thanks a lot  ^^

Comment: No problem, glad to see that my answer helps. =)